# Matplotlib: (Automating) Plotting unknown number of data sources/line/plots on 1 subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, python-3.4

(Sorry for my title not being great!)

Ok, so I'm trying to automate one of my plotting codes. I think this is the better board to use (i.e. rather than Code Review) as it's a question with a specific goal rather than generally improving it. Apologies if I'm mistaken in my assessment of this.

For this I need to be able to plot an unknown number of different data sources (what will form lines on the plot); all within the same subplot. Must things I have found are geared up for having a new subplot for each data source which is not what I'm after.

Example code for if I have say 3 data sources:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_y1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
data_x1 = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]

data_y2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 2]
data_x2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10]

data_y3 = [1, 3, 5, 7]
data_x3 = [1, 4, 9, 16]

fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)

a1, = ax1.plot(data_x1, data_y1, label="Data 1", color='g')
a2, = ax1.plot(data_x2, data_y2, label="Data 2", color='r')
a3, = ax1.plot(data_x3, data_y3, label="Data 3", color='c')

ax1.set_xlabel("Number of Hellos", fontsize=15)
ax1.set_ylabel("Number of Worlds", fontsize=18)

fig1.legend( (a1, a2, a3), ("Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3"), loc='lower center', fancybox=True, ncol=3, fontsize=20)

mng = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
mng.window.showMaximized()

plt.show()
```

So that works. However my problem is, I have no idea how many data sources I'll have. It could be 10 (e.g. data_y10, etc.) or it could just be the one. So I can't do say (a1, a2, a3) I'm struggling to automate this. I've been trying to use dictionaries, however they seem to mess up the legend.

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have all your data in a list of lists:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import cycle

def main():

    colors = cycle(["aqua", "black", "blue", "fuchsia", "gray", "green", "lime", "maroon", "navy", "olive", "purple", "red", "silver", "teal", "yellow"])

    data = [
        [
            [1,   2, 3,   4, 5],
            [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3]
        ], 
        [
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,  2],
            [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 10]
        ], 
        [
            [1, 3, 5,  7],
            [1, 4, 9, 16]
        ]
    ]

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    for i, item in enumerate(data):
        ax.plot(item[0], item[1], label="Data " + str(i), color=next(colors))

    ax.set_xlabel("Number of Hellos", fontsize=15)
    ax.set_ylabel("Number of Worlds", fontsize=18)

    ax.legend(loc="best")

    ax.margins(0.1)
    fig.tight_layout()

    plt.savefig("mwe.png")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: Can't see why I can't store my data in a list of lists! Will try implementing this in a moment and accept the answer if it works (can't see it not). Thanks for the help!

Comment: Spot on, does exactly what I was looking for it to. Thanks a million!